# Plotting a function with more than one variable in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, calculus

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")
x, y, z, t = sym.symbols('x y z t')
```

We were given a function in class to write as code

```
\begin{equation}
p_w(z,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \left(1-\exp\left[-2 t\right]\right)}}
\exp\left[-\frac{\left(z-\exp\left[-t\right]\right)^{2}}{1-
\exp\left[-2t\right]}\right]
\end{equation}
```

which I have written as this

```
p_w = (1/(sym.sqrt((sym.pi)*(1-(sym.exp(-2*t))))))*(sym.exp((-(z-sym.exp(-t))**2)/(1-sym.exp(-2*t))))
```

Then find the partial differential equation

```
∂(,)=∂[(,)]+1/2 ∂2(,)
```

which I have written as this:

```
LHS=sym.diff(p_w,t,1)
#differentiate once with respect to t
RHS=sym.diff(z*p_w,z,1)+((1/2)*(sym.diff(p_w,z,2)))
#now differentiate with respect to z
```

Now we need to plot it and can only use matplotlib/numpy/sympy libraries.

> > > Plot (,) for the three values t=0.1,1,10 in a (,) versus z diagram.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
t_points=[0.1,1,10]
#pw = sym.lambdify(t,p_w)
mytspace=np.linspace(0,10,200)
#myzspace=pw(mytspace)
plt.xlabel("t axis")
plt.ylabel("z axis")
plt.plot(t_array,np.zeros(3),'bs')
```

I haven't studied multivariable calculus before so I'm a bit lost!

Comment: Since `t` has been given (as 0.1, 1, and 10) you're only actually plotting with one variable, and your graphs will just be 2D. So just plot as normal but loop over your three values of `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of your variables is given (you know `t` must be `t=0.1`, `t=1` or `t=10`) your only variable for plotting is `z`. I know you are using `sympy` for the calculations, but for plotting maybe it's simpler to just return `p_w` as a `numpy` array. You can define a function to return `p_w` as so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def p_w(z, t):
    p_w = (1/(np.sqrt((np.pi)*(1-(np.exp(-2*t))))))*(np.exp((-(z-np.exp(-t))**2)/(1-np.exp(-2*t))))
    return p_w
```

This will give you a numpy array with the results of `p_w(z, t)` where `z` is an array and `t` is just one number. Then you can just iterate over the values of `t` that you need:

```
t_points=[0.1, 1, 10]
z = np.linspace(0,10,200)

for t in t_points:
    plt.plot(z, p_w(z, t), label='t = {0}'.format(t))   

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]